# How do I speed up this multi-statement tabled valued function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I wrote this function that feeds into an XSLT tool for reporting.  It's incredibly slow, taking about 1.5-2 seconds on average to return 100 rows.  This gets worse as this query can return up to 2000 rows.  Any sort of excess load is causing the query to time out, so now I need to optimize it.

```
USE [ININ_SID]

GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[GetProjectData]    Script Date: 12/30/2011 10:27:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetProjectData] (
-- Add the parameters for the function here
@ProjectNo VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS @Final TABLE (
  Customer             VARCHAR(250),
  ProjectNo            VARCHAR(50),
  ProjectName          VARCHAR(512),
  ProjectType          VARCHAR(100),
  PhaseID              INT,
  Phase                VARCHAR(50),
  NameField1           VARCHAR(100),
  IDField1             INT,
  IDField2             INT,
  ItemDescription      VARCHAR(100),
  Health               VARCHAR(6),
  CompletionPercentage INT,
  Status               VARCHAR(16),
  Owner                VARCHAR(64),
  ItemNotes            VARCHAR(140),
  ProjectNotes         VARCHAR(140))
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @Health TABLE (
        ProjectID    INT,
        ProjectNotes VARCHAR(140))
      DECLARE @Projects TABLE (
        ProjectID     INT PRIMARY KEY,
        ProjectSiteId INT,
        ProjectNo     VARCHAR(50),
        ProjectType   VARCHAR(100),
        ProjectName   VARCHAR(512),
        Customer      VARCHAR(250),
        UNIQUE (ProjectID))

      INSERT INTO @Projects
      SELECT PSO_Projects.ProjectID,
             ProjectSiteID,
             ProjectNo,
             ProjectType,
             ProjectName,
             Customers.Name AS Customer
      FROM   PSO_Projects
             INNER JOIN Customers
               ON Customers.CustomerID = PSO_Projects.CustomerID
      WHERE  PSO_Projects.ProjectNo = @ProjectNo
             AND CompletionDate IS NULL

      -- Get the latest health/notes for the projects
      -- This will be used in an inner join later
      INSERT INTO @Health
      SELECT ProjectID,
             ProjectNotes
      FROM   (SELECT ProjectID,
                     Notes                                                              AS ProjectNotes,
                     Rank() OVER (Partition BY ProjectID ORDER BY LastUpdatedDate DESC) AS Rank
              FROM   PSO_ProjectHealthEntries) tmp
      WHERE  Rank = 1
             AND ProjectID IN (SELECT ProjectID
                               FROM   @Projects)

      -- PROJECT DELIVERABLES
      INSERT INTO @Final
                  (Customer,
                   ProjectNo,
                   ProjectName,
                   ProjectType,
                   PhaseID,
                   Phase,
                   NameField1,
                   IDField1,
                   IDField2,
                   ItemDescription,
                   Health,
                   CompletionPercentage,
                   Status,
                   Owner,
                   ItemNotes,
                   ProjectNotes)
      SELECT Customer,
             ProjectNo,
             ProjectName,
             ProjectType,
             PSO_phases.PhaseID,
             PSO_Phases.Name,
             PSO_Phases.PhaseType,
             PSO_Deliverables.DeliverableID,
             PSO_Deliverables.MasterID,
             PSO_Deliverables.Name,
             PSO_Deliverables.Health,
             PSO_Deliverables.CompletionPercentage,
             pso_deliverables.Status,
             DeliverableContacts.Name,
             PSO_Deliverables.Notes,
             Health.ProjectNotes
      FROM   @Projects Projects
             INNER JOIN @Health Health
               ON Health.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID
             INNER JOIN PSO_Phases
               ON PSO_Phases.ProjectSiteID = Projects.ProjectSiteID
             LEFT JOIN PSO_Deliverables
               ON PSO_Deliverables.PhaseID = PSO_Phases.PhaseID
             LEFT JOIN PSO_DeliverableAssociations
               ON PSO_DeliverableAssociations.DeliverableID = PSO_Deliverables.DeliverableID
                  AND PSO_DeliverableAssociations.Active = 1
             LEFT JOIN PSO_ProjectContacts DeliverableContacts
               ON DeliverableContacts.ContactID = PSO_DeliverableAssociations.ContactID
      WHERE  PSO_Phases.Name  'System Development & Deployment'
             AND PSO_Deliverables.Type NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ManagementGroup
                                               FROM   PSO_DeliverableOwnership)
             AND Projects.ProjectID IN (SELECT ProjectID
                                        FROM   @Projects)

      -- ADDON DELIVERABLES
      INSERT INTO @Final
                  (Customer,
                   ProjectNo,
                   ProjectName,
                   ProjectType,
                   PhaseID,
                   Phase,
                   NameField1,
                   IDField1,
                   IDField2,
                   ItemDescription,
                   Health,
                   CompletionPercentage,
                   Status,
                   Owner,
                   ItemNotes,
                   ProjectNotes)
      SELECT Customer,
             ProjectNo,
             ProjectName,
             ProjectType,
             PSO_Phases.PhaseID,
             'Add-On Deliverables',
             PSO_Deliverables.SubType,
             PSO_Deliverables.DeliverableID,
             PSO_Deliverables.MasterID,
             PSO_Deliverables.Name + ' (' + PSO_Deliverables.SubType + ')',
             PSO_Deliverables.Health,
             PSO_Deliverables.CompletionPercentage,
             PSO_Deliverables.Status,
             PSO_ProjectContacts.Name,
             PSO_Deliverables.Notes,
             Health.ProjectNotes
      FROM   @Projects Projects
             INNER JOIN @Health Health
               ON Health.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID
             INNER JOIN PSO_Phases
               ON PSO_Phases.ProjectSiteID = Projects.ProjectSiteID
             INNER JOIN PSO_Deliverables
               ON PSO_Deliverables.PhaseID = PSO_Phases.PhaseID
             LEFT JOIN PSO_DeliverableAssociations
               ON PSO_DeliverableAssociations.DeliverableID = PSO_Deliverables.DeliverableID
                  AND PSO_DeliverableAssociations.Active = 1
             LEFT JOIN PSO_ProjectContacts
               ON PSO_ProjectContacts.ContactID = PSO_DeliverableAssociations.ContactID
      WHERE  Projects.ProjectID IN (SELECT ProjectID
                                    FROM   @Projects)
             AND ( PSO_Deliverables.Type IN (SELECT DISTINCT ManagementGroup
                                             FROM   PSO_DeliverableOwnership) )

      -- PROJECT  SITE NAMES ONLY
      INSERT INTO @Final
                  (Customer,
                   ProjectNo,
                   ProjectName,
                   ProjectType,
                   PhaseID,
                   Phase,
                   NameField1,
                   IDField1,
                   IDField2,
                   ItemDescription,
                   Health,
                   CompletionPercentage,
                   Status,
                   Owner,
                   ItemNotes,
                   ProjectNotes)
      SELECT Customer,
             ProjectNo,
             ProjectName,
             ProjectType,
             0,
             'Systems Development and Deployment',
             PSO_Sites.Name,
             PSO_Sites.SiteID,
             PSO_Sites.SiteID,
             PSO_Sites.Name,
             '' AS Health,
             '' AS CompletionPercentage,
             '' AS Status,
             '' AS Owner,
             '' AS Notes,
             Health.ProjectNotes
      FROM   @Projects Projects
             INNER JOIN @Health Health
               ON Health.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID
             INNER JOIN PSO_Sites
               ON PSO_Sites.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID
      WHERE  Projects.ProjectID IN (SELECT ProjectID
                                    FROM   @Projects)

      RETURN
  END
```

And on top of this, order is extremely important.  This is how it's called:

```
SELECT Data.*
FROM   PSO_Projects
       INNER JOIN PSO_ProjectAssociations
         ON PSO_ProjectAssociations.ProjectID = PSO_Projects.ProjectID
            AND PSO_ProjectAssociations.Active = 1
       INNER JOIN PSO_ProjectContacts
         ON PSO_ProjectContacts.ContactID = PSO_ProjectAssociations.ContactID
       CROSS apply Getprojectdata(ProjectNo) Data
WHERE  PSO_ProjectContacts.Name = 'John.Smith'
       AND PSO_Projects.CompletionDate IS NULL
ORDER  BY Customer,
          ProjectNo,
          CASE
            WHEN Phase = 'Initiation' THEN PhaseID
            WHEN Phase = 'Planning' THEN PhaseID + 2000
            WHEN Phase = 'Requirements & Design' THEN PhaseID + 4000
            WHEN Phase = 'Systems Development and Deployment' THEN PhaseID + 6000
            WHEN Phase = 'Add-On Deliverables' THEN PhaseID + 8000
            WHEN Phase = 'Closing' THEN PhaseID + 10000
            ELSE PhaseID
          END,
          IDField2,
          IDField1
```

Is there anything I can do in the query to optimize this?  The only other real option I have is to find a way to refactor the report to be able to handle fewer columns (such as returning the project name/customer in a single row instead of including it with every row)  but I'm not sure how feasible this is.

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the tables?

Comment: Yes, there are several indexes on each table.  Some of the crazier ones (that index multiple columns) were suggested by SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: My thought is you need to refactor to not have a table valued function.  That function does a lot of work and is called for each row.   I suspect those joins in the TVF are processed multiple times.  Try and re factor this as a single query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a quick hit, just take out your `not in` and use `not exists`, and all of your `in` statements checking the ProjectID are useless. Make the insert into `@Final` one `unioned` statement, like so:

```
SELECT 
    Customer,
    ProjectNo,
    ProjectName,
    ProjectType,
    PSO_phases.PhaseID,
    PSO_Phases.Name,
    PSO_Phases.PhaseType,
    PSO_Deliverables.DeliverableID,
    PSO_Deliverables.MasterID,
    PSO_Deliverables.Name,
    PSO_Deliverables.Health,
    PSO_Deliverables.CompletionPercentage,
    pso_deliverables.Status,
    DeliverableContacts.Name,
    PSO_Deliverables.Notes,
    Health.ProjectNotes
FROM   
    @Projects Projects
     INNER JOIN @Health Health
       ON Health.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID
     INNER JOIN PSO_Phases
       ON PSO_Phases.ProjectSiteID = Projects.ProjectSiteID
     LEFT JOIN PSO_Deliverables
       ON PSO_Deliverables.PhaseID = PSO_Phases.PhaseID
     LEFT JOIN PSO_DeliverableAssociations
       ON PSO_DeliverableAssociations.DeliverableID = PSO_Deliverables.DeliverableID
          AND PSO_DeliverableAssociations.Active = 1
     LEFT JOIN PSO_ProjectContacts DeliverableContacts
       ON DeliverableContacts.ContactID = PSO_DeliverableAssociations.ContactID
WHERE  
    PSO_Phases.Name = 'System Development & Deployment'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            PSO_DeliverableOwnership
        where
            PSO_Deliverables.Type = ManagementGroup
    )
union all
SELECT Customer,
     ProjectNo,
     ProjectName,
     ProjectType,
     PSO_Phases.PhaseID,
     'Add-On Deliverables',
     PSO_Deliverables.SubType,
     PSO_Deliverables.DeliverableID,
     PSO_Deliverables.MasterID,
     PSO_Deliverables.Name + ' (' + PSO_Deliverables.SubType + ')',
     PSO_Deliverables.Health,
     PSO_Deliverables.CompletionPercentage,
     PSO_Deliverables.Status,
     PSO_ProjectContacts.Name,
     PSO_Deliverables.Notes,
     Health.ProjectNotes
FROM   @Projects Projects
     INNER JOIN @Health Health
       ON Health.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID
     INNER JOIN PSO_Phases
       ON PSO_Phases.ProjectSiteID = Projects.ProjectSiteID
     INNER JOIN PSO_Deliverables
       ON PSO_Deliverables.PhaseID = PSO_Phases.PhaseID
     LEFT JOIN PSO_DeliverableAssociations
       ON PSO_DeliverableAssociations.DeliverableID = PSO_Deliverables.DeliverableID
          AND PSO_DeliverableAssociations.Active = 1
     LEFT JOIN PSO_ProjectContacts
       ON PSO_ProjectContacts.ContactID = PSO_DeliverableAssociations.ContactID
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            PSO_DeliverableOwnership
        where
            PSO_Deliverables.Type = ManagementGroup
    )
union all
SELECT Customer,
     ProjectNo,
     ProjectName,
     ProjectType,
     0,
     'Systems Development and Deployment',
     PSO_Sites.Name,
     PSO_Sites.SiteID,
     PSO_Sites.SiteID,
     PSO_Sites.Name,
     '' AS Health,
     '' AS CompletionPercentage,
     '' AS Status,
     '' AS Owner,
     '' AS Notes,
     Health.ProjectNotes
FROM   @Projects Projects
     INNER JOIN @Health Health
       ON Health.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID
     INNER JOIN PSO_Sites
       ON PSO_Sites.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a start at pulling the @tables into one query.  Keep building until you have one query. This can be one query (with unions)  For the not in or not exists typically a left outer join then search on null for the right hand table will give the best performance.

```
    SELECT Customer,
         ProjectNo,
         ProjectName,
         ProjectType,
         PSO_phases.PhaseID,
         PSO_Phases.Name,
         PSO_Phases.PhaseType,
         PSO_Deliverables.DeliverableID,
         PSO_Deliverables.MasterID,
         PSO_Deliverables.Name,
         PSO_Deliverables.Health,
         PSO_Deliverables.CompletionPercentage,
         pso_deliverables.Status,
         DeliverableContacts.Name,
         PSO_Deliverables.Notes,
         Health.ProjectNotes
  FROM   PSO_Projects
         INNER JOIN Customers
           ON Customers.CustomerID = PSO_Projects.CustomerID
           AND CompletionDate IS NULL          
         INNER JOIN PSO_Phases
           ON PSO_Phases.ProjectSiteID = Projects.ProjectSiteID
         LEFT JOIN PSO_Deliverables
           ON PSO_Deliverables.PhaseID = PSO_Phases.PhaseID
         LEFT JOIN PSO_DeliverableAssociations
           ON PSO_DeliverableAssociations.DeliverableID = PSO_Deliverables.DeliverableID
              AND PSO_DeliverableAssociations.Active = 1
         LEFT JOIN PSO_ProjectContacts DeliverableContacts
           ON DeliverableContacts.ContactID = PSO_DeliverableAssociations.ContactID
         INNER JOIN @Health Health
           ON Health.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID
         left outer join PSO_DeliverableOwnership 
           ON SO_DeliverableOwnership.ManagementGroup = PSO_Deliverables.Type
  WHERE  PSO_Phases.Name  = 'System Development & Deployment'
         AND PSO_Projects.ProjectNo = @ProjectNo 
         AND PSO_Projects.CompletionDate IS NULL
         AND SO_DeliverableOwnership.ManagementGroup is null
```

Agree on union

An the @Health I think would do that at a function

```
 SELECT top 1 Notes from PSO_ProjectHealthEntries where ProjectID = @inputID
```

No doubt I some errors but where you are joining to @table replace that with actual join. The @tables don't have PK, FK for the query optimizer use.